# Retirar aspas de uma string json com replace typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso retirar as aspas de uma string que recebo em json, para isso estou criando um pipe, porém não estou conseguindo retirar as aspas duplas.

Tentei algo como:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'prettyprint'
})
export class PrettyPrintPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val) {
    return JSON.stringify(val, null, 2)
      .replace("\"", "")
      .replace("{", "")
      .replace("}", "");
  }
}

Também tentei:
 .replace(`""`, "")
```

Mas sem sucesso, as aspas não saem.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar REGEX para "excluir" as aspas? <https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp>

Comment: tenta o famoso symbol('"');